# Algorithm for split network into two or more than two mutually exclusive subset of nodes

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Suppose I have large network dataset which contains edge-list . I'd like to splits (homogeneously or hetrogeneously) network structure  into two or more than communities in such a way a way that every vertex belongs to one of the communities.
[this image have three small subnetworks or communities are connected to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NedaB.png)

Comment: From the formulation it is a bit unclear what the desired properties of the result are. As trivial solutions, einter each node can be a single community or there is one community containing every node.